# How do I add 2 elements for each iteration in a python shorthand list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, shorthand

I want to write a list like `[i*2, i*3 for i in range(10)]` so that I can have an output of `[0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 8, 12...]` (so for each element in the `range(10)` I want to add 2 elements to the list from two calculations).

Comment: `[x for i in range(10) for x in (i * 2, i * 3)]`? Note it will also include two zeros.

Comment: Why are the best answers always left as comments @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

```py
[ i*k for i in range(10) for k in (2, 3) ]
```

**Original:**

Just keeping it simple with list comprehension:

```py
[ i*k for i in range(10) for k in range(2,4) ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, or [any other Python iterable-flattening approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists):

```py
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(i*2, i*3) for i in range(10)]))
[0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 8, 12, 10, 15, 12, 18, 14, 21, 16, 24, 18, 27]
```

Comment: Don't really need to pass as list: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((i*2, i*3) for i in range(10)))`. its fine to just pass a generator.

Answer (score 1):

How about two for statements in a list comprehension?

```
[i*j for i in range(10) for j in [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum((map(lambda x: [x*2, x*3], range(10))), [])
```

output

```
[0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 8, 12, 10, 15, 12, 18, 14, 21, 16, 24, 18, 27]
```

we can do it this way too, without any loops.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is irrelevant? can anyone please explain?

Comment: It's relevant but I gues it's less efficient than other answers... idk